# C# ASP.NET display code on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-formatting

I would like to read in a .cs file from my project which contains a code sample for use by clients of my company's API.

What's the best way to read in this file and pretty-print it to the page with indentations etc.  The goal is to just have the code on the page automatically change when I update the contents of this file so that the code sample will always be up to date as published on the live site.

An example of what I'm attempting to accomplish is something similar to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this...

http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/

http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/CSharpFormat.zip

It transforms C# code into html.  You can read the file run it through the CSharpFormat then output the HTML to a panel in the page.